# Get all dates between 2 dates out database per sort of item

Tags: php, mysql, innodb, where-clause

I'm trying to get an array of each car with the dates the car is hired.

So far I have a function which gets all the dates from all invoice lines instead of an array for each car its own. How can I get this to work?

My goal will be to get a list of cars which are available in the selected period but first I'm trying to get it to work with static start and end date. 
I was thinking to get a loop which gets all different car id's and for each car id it will create an array which contains all the dates.

```
<?php
$start_date = '2017-06-12';
$end_date = '2017-06-14';
$items = array();

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM invoice_line ");
$carid = null;
while ($car = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $carid =  $car['car_car_id'];
  echo $carid;
  //second part
  $car = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM invoice_line WHERE car_car_id = '$carid' AND start_date>='$start_date' AND end_date<='$end_date'");
  while ($car_available = mysqli_fetch_array($car)) {
  echo $car_available['car_car_id'];
  }
} // end second part

?>
<?php
function getDateRange($startDate, $endDate, $format="Y-m-d")
{
    //Create output variable
    $datesArray = array();
    //Calculate number of days in the range
    $total_days = round(abs(strtotime($endDate) - strtotime($startDate)) / 86400, 0) + 1;
    //Populate array of weekdays and counts
    for($day=0; $day<$total_days; $day++)
    {
        $datesArray[] = date($format, strtotime("{$startDate} + {$day} days"));
    }
    //Return results array
    return $datesArray;
}
?>
```

Update:
I changed the code to what i have now based on the comments, instead of giving me all the cars which are not in use its giving me the cars where the start and end date are somewhere between the $start_date end $end_date. So how can i use this to get a list of the cars which are not used that period. Under here is a example of the DB as you can see the can be multiple records with the same can but in a different time period. For example if $start_date is 2017-02-03 and $end_date is 2017-02-05 car number 1 and 3 should be there but if the start_date is 2017-06-11 end and date is 2017-06-13 only car number one should be there because there is a record of this car being used in this period.

[image: data]

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.6.4
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: localhost:8889
-- Generation Time: Jun 11, 2017 at 10:43 AM
-- Server version: 5.6.28
-- PHP Version: 7.0.10

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

--
-- Database: `rentacar`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `invoice_line`
--

CREATE TABLE `invoice_line` (
  `car_car_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `invoice_invoice_number` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `start_date` date NOT NULL,
  `end_date` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `invoice_line`
--

INSERT INTO `invoice_line` (`car_car_id`, `invoice_invoice_number`, `start_date`, `end_date`) VALUES
(3, 2, '2017-06-12', '2017-06-14'),
(2, 2, '2017-06-10', '2017-06-20'),
(1, 1, '2017-06-01', '2017-06-03');

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--
```

Comment: its a lot more efficient to have the filter on the sql statement, so that you only get the ones you need, unless you need the whole list elsewhere

Comment: Ok i dont need this list anywhere else but im not that good with query's but ill look into it now

Comment: SELECT * FROM invoice_line WHERE car_id = $car and start_date>='$start_date' and end_date<='$end_date'

Comment: @Isac this doesn't get all the cars which are not hired right but only the ones that are between the start and end date?

Comment: Yes, with your last comment i realize i misinterpreted what you intended to do. However, you can filter the invoice_lines with WHERE end_date >= '$start_date' and start_date <='$end_date' to give you the cars that may be used in that period, still requires analysis as you were doing

Comment: @mickmackusa Updated the question i hope its more clear now what needs to be done and what i did with the comment from isac

Comment: @mickmackusa That was my first idea but isac told me its more efficient to filter the cars with a sql query instead of getting arrays so what i think i need is a query which gets the cars which are not used in the period between $start_date and $end_date

Comment: @mickmackusa yes but since there is another record with car_id 3, car number 3 still show up but its shouldnt because it is being used in another record

Comment: @mickmackusa added sql dump of the table without foreign keys since  they are not relevant with this question but if you do need it tell me and ill dump the whole db

Comment: I cannot fathom the point of the first query. Get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a result depicting the date each car was hired:

```
SELECT * FROM invoice_line;
+--------+----------------+------------+------------+
| car_id | invoice_number | start_date | end_date   |
+--------+----------------+------------+------------+
|      3 |              2 | 2017-06-12 | 2017-06-14 |
|      2 |              2 | 2017-06-10 | 2017-06-20 |
|      1 |              1 | 2017-06-01 | 2017-06-03 |
+--------+----------------+------------+------------+
```

You can transform it to an array just like you would any other result.

Note I've amended the column names slightly, in order to preserve my sanity.

Comment: Another commentor suggested that this totally be handled in sql and now that's what the OP is going for.  I haven't had time to try anything yet, and I think I need to ask the OP about how to handle multiple qualifying rows with the same `car_id`...  but can't this be done with a WHERE NOT IN [subquery] ?  OP want to see all qualifying rows that are not (separately) disqualified.   (it is a confusing question)